# Is there any injective homomorphism (i.e. monomorphism) from a non-cyclic group of order $4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_8$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

The only such possible group is $V$ (up to isomorphism). If $\phi$ be such an into homomorphism, then $o(\phi(V))=4$ and $\phi(V)$ being a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_8$, it must be cyclic with a generator of order $4$. But, $V$ has not element of order $4$. A contradiction.

Does this work?

Comment: What is an into homomorphism?

Comment: A monomorphism.

Comment: i.e. $\forall y \in \phi(G)$, $\{x \in G: \phi(x)=y\}$ has only one element.

Comment: It is a nice exercise to prove that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Your result follows immediately.

Answer (score 2):

That argument works. Given a monomorphism $f:G\to H$ between groups $G,H$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $f(G)$, and the two must therefore have the same number of elements of any given order.

Alternatively, there is only one element of order $2$ in $\Bbb Z_8$, while there are three in $V$.

Comment: Nice argument! Can you please post some links here to very similar group theory questions? (Contest math type). Thanks!

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas Any decent introductory group theory textbook should have lots of problems just like this one.

Comment: I am going through.